# Improve Performance of Gradient Border using CAShapeLayer and CAGradientLayer

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, core-animation, calayer

I am using this method to apply gradient border to views. But when the view is in a cell of a tableview, the scrolling frame rate of the table view drops significally. Is there a way to improve the performance ? I tried setting the opaque , drawsAsynchronously and shouldRasterize to true as Apple is suggesting but nothing changed.

```
func addBorder(colors:[UIColor]? = nil,size:CGSize? = nil) {



    _ = self.sublayers?.filter({$0.name == "GradientBorder"}).map({$0.removeFromSuperlayer()})
    let shapeFrame = CGRect(origin: CGPointZero, size: size ?? bounds.size)
    let gradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()
    gradientLayer.name = "GradientBorder"

    gradientLayer.frame =  shapeFrame
    gradientLayer.startPoint = CGPointMake(0.0, 0.5)
    gradientLayer.endPoint = CGPointMake(1.0, 0.5)
    gradientLayer.colors = colors == nil ? [UIColor.blueColor().CGColor,UIColor.redColor().CGColor] : colors!.map({$0.CGColor})
    gradientLayer.contentsScale = UIScreen.mainScreen().scale


    let shapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
    shapeLayer.lineWidth = 2

    shapeLayer.path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: shapeFrame, cornerRadius: self.cornerRadius).CGPath
    shapeLayer.fillColor = nil
    shapeLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.blackColor().CGColor


    gradientLayer.shouldRasterize = true
    gradientLayer.opaque = true
    gradientLayer.drawsAsynchronously  = true
    shapeLayer.drawsAsynchronously  = true
    shapeLayer.opaque = true

    gradientLayer.mask = shapeLayer
    self.addSublayer(gradientLayer)



}
```

Comment: When are you adding the border? Can you show that part of the code too?

Comment: @IBOutlet weak var isOnlineViewContainer: UIView! {
        didSet {
            isOnlineViewContainer.layer.addBorder()
        }
    }

Comment: Well, I mean the whole situation - how often is the addBorder function called?

Comment: I have a collectionView with around 50 cell. This IBOutlet is in the CollectionViewCell class. So its being called around 50 times.

Comment: Are you sure it's not called more often per cell, eg when the collectionview is scrolling?

Comment: Yeas i am sure. But as you can see i added this _ = self.sublayers?.filter({$0.name == "GradientBorder"}).map({$0.removeFromSuperlayer()}) witch prevent piling up sublayers

Comment: Yes - but you create the layer on every call, that takes time.

Comment: Yeah , but i don't have any other options here. Am i ?

Comment: Create it once when the cell is created, then store it for that cell - assuming it's the same size every time it's reused.

Answer (score 3):

Ok i found the solution and it was very easy. I simply added these three lines.

```
override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    // Initialization code
    self.layer.shouldRasterize = true
    self.opaque = true
    self.layer.rasterizationScale = UIScreen.mainScreen().scale
}
```